# Como saber el valor de un array

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Hace poco deje un código acerca de como crear id dinámicos en un ciclo `while`.

Ahora tengo esta otra duda.

```
<?php
 $i=1;
 $n=1
 while($fila=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
    $this->empleados[]=$filas;
    $Filas = consult_cedula($fila['Persona']);

                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo '<td>' . $Filas['codsucursal'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>' . $fila['Persona'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>' . $fila['Fecha'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>' . $fila['Hora'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>' . $Filas['nombre'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>' . $Filas['cargo'] . '</td>';

                echo '<td>' . '<input type="button" name="nom' . $n .'" id="btn"' . $i .'"" class="btn btn-danger" value="..." data-fech="' .
                  $fila['Fecha'] . '" data-hora="' . $fila['Hora'] . '" data-ced="' . $fila['Persona'] .
                  '" data-nom="' . $Filas['nombre'] . '" data-cargo="' . $Filas['cargo'] . '">';

                 echo "</tr>";


                 $i=$i+1;
                 $n=$n+1;

             }
```

Ese es el código y como pueden ver, el id ya es dinámico. Ahora, por cada vuelta el id es diferente, pero ¿cómo hago para capturar, por ejemplo, el segundo id con jQuery?
*Estoy permitiendo que esta consulta solo me de 5 resultados para no hacerlo tan extenso.*

Comment: Si especificamente quieres capturar el segundo id deberías validarlo con un `if`, cuando `$i == 2`

Comment: tu dices al presionar el boton ? o te refieres al recorrer toda la tabla?

Comment: a travez de esa consulta. necesito hacer una insersión. necesito saber el valor de cada id para poder hacer la insercion con ajax, me explico?

Comment: entonces hay un ingreso de datos , pero para poder insertar necesita recorrer los botones de  la tabla para insertar un registro diferente?

Comment: aja .. esa es la idea mi pana

Comment: Pero si necesitas ingresar **CADA** registro en la BD no necesitas obtener el `id` no? Simplemente realizas la operacion de insersión y ya está, como los `ids` son dinámicos no se duplicarán en la BD (teniendo en cuenta que entra al bucle sólo una vez) O habré entendido mal el problema? =/

Comment: Deberías agregar una clase a todo los botones, por ejemplo btn_table, luego puedes capturar todos los botones con $('.btn_table')  y obtener el id con $('.btn_table').attr('id')

Comment: por ejemplo, este bucle se ejecuta 5 veces, verdad? osea, me va a lista 5 personas. como hago, por ejemplo, para hacer el registro de la tercera persona sin antes hacer las 2 primeras?

Comment: con este ejemplo que me acabas de dar me perdí más , ahora no entiendo si necesitas insertar el registro en la tabla o necesitas insertar antes de que cargue los registros, como es esto?, Yo que tu hago denuevo esa pregunta, porque no te entiendo.

Comment: ya hice la consulta. pero la consulta la necesito insertar a una tabla mediante ajax. pero, con javascript, necesito capturar el valor de cada id que se ejecuta en la consulta para poder hacer la insersion...

Comment: en escencia, como hago para capturar el valor $i que el id dinamico, en javascript

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que necesitas el código debería ser el siguiente:

```
<?php
 $i=1;
 $n=1
 while(condicion)
 {
    // Suponiendo que $i es tu id y necesitas especificamente el id con valor 2
    if($i == 2){
       //Insersion en BD
    }

    $i=$i+1;
    $n=$n+1;

  }
?>
```

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas y te sirvió

Comment: el problema es que el valor de $i lo debo capturar con jquery y hacer la insersion mediante ajax. lo que no he podido es  como capturar $i en javascript (ya que es dinamico)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239598/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-an-element-using-jquery debería solucionar eso =)

Answer (score 0):

Según tu informacion se me ocurre de esta manera obtener los id de los botones dentro de la tabla

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
 $('#tabla').find('input').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table border="1" id="tabla">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Columna1</th>
    <th>Columna2</th>
    <th>Columna3</th>
    <th>Columna4</th>
    <th>Columna5</th>
    <th>Columna6</th>
  </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td> 
      <td><input type="button" value="Boton1" id="1"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td> 
      <td><input type="button" value="Boton2" id="2"> </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td> 
      <td><input type="button" value="Boton3" id="3"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td> 
      <td><input type="button" value="Boton4" id="4"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
  </table>
```

Lo que hago con ese código es que recorro todos los input de forma ordenada y obtengo el valor del atributo `id` y lo imprimo con console.log. Avísame si te ayuda. Saludos!.